# Hide Nav Bar when Presenting a New Controller

Tags: objective-c

When a button is clicked, the end user is able to send an email. However the nav bar won't go away, and the email nav bar is hidden underneath the main one. Is there a way to hide the main one? This is the action that is called when the button is pressed:

```
-(void)goToEmail{
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailCont setSubject:@"Hello!"];
        [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name@email.com"]];
        [mailCont setMessageBody:@"Test" isHTML:NO];

        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailCont animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);` and make sure it is not `(null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.navigationController.navigationBar` is the mail controller's navigation controller. Therefore, you're hiding the email navigation bar, not the main one. You shouldn't have to hide the main one at all. Take that call (`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];`) out and see what you get. You should see the mail controller in front of the other, showing a nav bar. The main nav bar will still be visible, but it will be behind.

Comment: This is the code that is setting up the mail task so self is not the main controller.

Comment: What did taking out that call accomplish? Did the navigation bar appear on top?

Comment: It didn't work. It turns out that self.navigationController is null, so i'm not sure what to do now

Comment: I think you've set up your navigation/view controllers throughout your app in a way that isn't useful. Where are you calling this method from? Which view controller?

Comment: i have a tabbarcontroller and on the first tab is a tableview and when you click on a cell it pushes another viewcontroller and on that is a button that i want to open an email

Comment: i fixed it! i shared the navController from the tableview with the viewcontroller that it pushed. and hid it when the button is pressed. thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Would you mind marking the answer as solved because it pushed you in the right direction?